# "sudo btrfs filesystem defragment -r /" can't defrag immutabe files, right?

Tags: filesystem, btrfs, defrag

Files made immutable by sudo chattr +i can't be defragmented by "sudo btrfs filesystem defragment". I get the message:
"ERROR: defrag failed on /path/filename: Success
total 1 failure"
Is this a bug or not?